# System.out.printf not working with Integer

Tags: java

When I type this part of code below it gives me an error message next to the System.out.printf line.

It tells me that I should replace the Integer type for `i` into `Object[]`.

However in the tutorial I am following the part below works and doesn't give any error messages. So is there something i did wrong here or what is the correct type then?

```
    for(int i=0; i < 5;i = i + 1) {
        System.out.printf("The value of i is: %d\n", i);
    }
```

Comment: Your code works fine. You can check here: http://ideone.com/NuAEwg.

Comment: Works for me, see: http://ideone.com/5yydqO - What is the version of your compiler? Could you provide the full code, with the class, and all the boilerplate?

Comment: The same for me, I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code which you are trying to run?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: Are you sure that it is an error message and not just a warning?

Comment: At least show the import section.

Comment: I suspect that this is a compiler or IDE bug in the version you are using.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Also, check the version of the JDK and lanugage level version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get, and print its value, this way:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5;i = i + 1) {
    System.out.printf("The value of i is: %d\n", Integer.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: The original post should work, 'cause of autoboxing.

Comment: Going by the description in the question, I think that @Bram is not accessing variable 'i' correctly. It is not supposed to be accessed as an array element.

Comment: @Bhoot - it is not being accessed as an array element!  The reason the compiler is suggestion `Object[]` is that the last argument of `printf` is var-args.

Comment: @StephenC: Wow. I did not know that. Thank you for bringing this up and I apologize for spreading my ignorance.